# JVM killed by MappedByteBuffer

Tags: java, jvm

I have this function:

```
    private double[] readTableDouble(final RandomAccessFile file, final long startIndex, final int length) throws IOException {
    double[] doubles;
    try (FileChannel channel = file.getChannel()) {
        MappedByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startIndex * 8, length * 8);
        int byteIndex = buffer.limit() - 8;
        doubles = new double[length];
        int doubleIndex = 0;
        while (byteIndex > 0 && doubleIndex < length) {
            long l = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                l |= ((long) (buffer.get(byteIndex + i) & 0xFF)) << i * 8;
            }
            byteIndex -= 8;
            if (l != fillerLong) {
                doubles[doubleIndex++] = Double.longBitsToDouble(l);
            }
        }
        if (doubleIndex == length) {
            file.close();
            channel.close();
            return doubles;
        }

        // try again from the start if not enough numbers
        buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, (startIndex + length) * 8);
        byteIndex = buffer.limit() - 8;
        doubleIndex = 0;
        while (byteIndex > 0 && doubleIndex < length) {
            long l = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                l |= ((long) (buffer.get(byteIndex + i) & 0xFF)) << i * 8;
            }
            byteIndex -= 8;
            if (l != fillerLong) {
                doubles[doubleIndex++] = Double.longBitsToDouble(l);
            }
        }
    }
    file.close();
    return doubles;
}
```

For some reason it kills JVM with the following error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x000000077f280000, 13107200, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 13107200 bytes for committing reserved memory.
An error report file with more information is saved as:
/home/lukasz/Documents/NetBeansProjects/PPP/hs_err_pid8817.log
Java Result: 1
```

This function is called hundreds of thousands times, however returned buffers are freed quickly. No multi threading, files are around 340kB.

Any ideas why? Profiler gets killed together with JVM.

Comment: Nearly impossible to tell the reason, I guess, but the `hs_err_pid8817.log` might contain some interesting information. You might want to add the *relevant* parts of this file (stack trace etc), maybe someone can interpret them

Comment: The most likely cause is that your total number of mappings have exceeded some OS limit (you're mapping read-only, so it should only be virtual space, rather than actual commit charge). I'm not writing this as an answer because IMO there is no reason for you to use a mapped buffer in this situation.

Comment: And why, pray tell, are you shifting bits to create a `double`, when you can just call `getDouble()`? Or better, turn your `ByteBuffer` into a `DoubleBuffer`?

Comment: @kdgregory: I have to use mapping as it is the fastest way. I have to shift bits by hand as I don't want to rely on endiannes. Plus I need to check for number == filler. Re: total number of mappings: I do only one file at a time. How to tell JVM to unmap the buffer?

Comment: I think you're getting far lower performance from memory-mapping than you think you are, but I'm not going to waste my time or yours trying to convince you of that. If you want to hack your way to cleaning up the buffers, take a look at the DirectByteBuffer code (in src.jar or on grepcode).

Comment: @kdgregory Agreed. Last time I looked at this it was only 20% faster than conventional I/O for reading.

Answer (score 0):

There is no well-defined time at which the VM allocated by a `MappedByteBuffer` can be released, so it is never released. Opening lots of memory-mapped files in Java is therefore highly problematic.

Comment: Actually, direct buffers are managed by phantom references, so will be unmapped when the GC determines that there are no references. There are also some hacks to deal with the fact that you could be allocating large amounts of off-heap memory and small amounts of on-heap memory (so the GC would not normally run).

Comment: @kdgregory That must be new-ish. There's a bug report at Oracle that says almost exactly what I've said here.

Comment: At least since 1.6, and I'm pretty sure since 1.5. If you go to GrepCode, you can find the "max buffers" hack in Unsafe (I think), and the cleaner in DirectByteBuffer.